# Bootstrap panel tab with dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Heres an example of a panel with tabs and a dropdown:
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/panels-with-nav-tabs

Is there a way to make the dropdown button act as a tab itself, and the dropdown only appear if you click on that particular part of the tab (only if you click on the arrow, not the rest of the tab).

Comment: Do you mean like the navbar [here](http://malooflab.phytonetworks.org)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you are going for?
[image: split dropdown button for bootstrap]

If so, you can place the main button and the dropdown portion of the button within a button group like this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.location.href='#'">
    Split Dropdown
  </button>

  <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown Menu item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown Menu item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/w1e8baec/) is a fiddle of it in action. (Be sure to include the Bootstrap and JQuery resource links within your own project.)

**UPDATE:** [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/q6hm1r7m/1/) is a fiddle of a similar approach incorporated into panels.

This is what it looks like:

[image: split dropdown tab for bootstrap]

And this is the pertinent code (full code in fiddle):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

        <!-- Other tabs here -->

        <li class="dropdown btn-group">
          <a class="btn" href="#tab-main" data-toggle="tab">Tab w/ Dropdown - Main Tab</a>
          <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle">
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#tab-dropdown1" data-toggle="tab">Tab w/ Dropdown - Dropdown 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-dropdown2" data-toggle="tab">Tab w/ Dropdown - Dropdown 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="tab-content">

        <!-- Other panes here -->

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-main">Tab w/ Dropdown - Main Tab</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-dropdown1">Tab w/ Dropdown - Dropdown 1</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-dropdown2">Tab w/ Dropdown - Dropdown 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The only issue that I see with this approach is that if you are on a dropdown panel, you can't go back to that tab's main panel without clicking on a different tab first. That is because both the main and the dropdown tab are getting the `active` class, which inactivates the tabs (in addition  to adding styling that indicates the tab is selected). If this is an issue, you should be able to work around it with some JavaScript.